# Prove by induction that if this is divisible by 11, then this is also divisible by 11

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation

How would I do this? I tried using contradiction, but got stuck halfway through.
This unit is about induction, but I have no idea how I would use it to do this as it is not a sequence

> 4.6.15 (a) show that for any $k\in N$, if $2^{3k-1}+ 5\cdot 3^k$ is divisible by 11, then $2^{3(k+2)-1} + 5\cdot 3^{k+2}$ is also divisible by 11
>   $$(\forall k\in N)(\exists p\in Z)(\exists w\in Z)(2^{3k-1}+5\cdot 3^k = 11p)\Rightarrow(2^{3(k+2)-1}+5\cdot 3^{k+2})$$
>   we can prove this by contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you seem to have surmised, you shouldn't try proving this by induction; essentially you are proving an inductive-type implication (true for $n$ implies true for $n+2$) and you don't need induction for that. (In fact, the statement is false for e.g. $k=1$: $4+5\cdot 3=19$ is not divisible by $11$. It is true
for $k=2$ though, so by induction it will be true for all positive even integers.)

Second, you don't need contradiction since the direct proof is straightforward enough, though naturally you could make the direct proof into a contradiction proof artificially.

Anyway, a direct proof is as follows. Suppose $2^{3k-1}+5\cdot 3^k$ is divisible
by $11$, so $2^{3k-1}+5\cdot 3^k=11j$ for some integer $j$. On the other hand,
$$2^{3(k+2)-1}+5\cdot 3^{k+2}=2^{3k+6-1}+5\cdot 3^{k+2}=2^6\cdot 2^{3k-1}+5\cdot 9\cdot 3^{k}.$$
Now $2^6=64=55+9$, so 
$$2^{3(k+2)-1}+5\cdot 3^{k+2}=9(2^{3k-1}+5\cdot 3^{k})+55\cdot 2^{3k-1}=9(11j)+11(5\cdot 2^{3k-1})$$
and so pulling out the common factor of $11$,
$$2^{3(k+2)-1}+5\cdot 3^{k+2}=11(9j+5\cdot 2^{3k-1})$$
hence $11$ divides $2^{3(k+2)-1}+5\cdot 3^{k+2}$ as required.

Comment: @learning you are quite right, they should be correct now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
2^{3(k+2)-1}+5 \cdot 3^{k+2} &= 64 \cdot 2^{3k-1} + 9 \cdot 5 \cdot 3^k \\
&= (66-2)\cdot 2^{3k-1} + (11 -2)\cdot 5 \cdot 3^k\\
&= 66 \cdot 2^{3k-1} + 11 \cdot 3^k - 2(2^{3k-1} + 5 \cdot 3^{k+2})
\end{align*}
First term is a multiple of 11 and the second term is a multiple of 11 by hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $f(n)=2^{3n-1}+5\cdot3^n,$

eliminate $2^{3n}$ or $3^n$

to find either $$f(k+1)-2^3\cdot f(k)$$ or $$f(k+1)-3\cdot f(k)$$ to be divisible by $11$